# C# Browser change iframes body html by class

Tags: c#, html, iframe

I have a c# webbrowser control which loads a specific page with different number of iframes (the number can differ in each page).

Here is the html example of the iframe body I want to be able to edit,

```
<iframe class="example example1 example2">
    #document
    <html>
        <body>
            content here.
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

The class of the iframe can vary but `example` and `example1` class will always be there. 
I want to be able to edit the content inside the body, by removing `content here.` and adding `new content.`.

This are the codes I have tried till now,

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(el.OuterHtml);
}
```

This shows 3 message box with 3 iframes but none of them were the one I was looking for.

I have also tried doing a foreach with

```
foreach(HTMLFrameBase frame in webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames)
{
    MessageBox.Show(frame.innerHTML);
}
```

but this gives invalid cast error.

Comment: You can use [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to change anything in HTML document.

Comment: I want to be able to change it directly cause after editing it there is a post function.